# image WriteableBitmap image .Pixels The field, constructor or member 'Pixels' is not defined?

Tags: .net, graphics, f#, writeablebitmap

```
    let image = WriteableBitmap(100, 100, 300.0, 300.0, Media.PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);
            let pixel = image.Pixels
```

Error   2   The field, constructor or member 'Pixels' is not defined

WriteableBitmap.Pixels Property MSDN

Why not defined?

Is this a framework issue? or ... scope? or ?

Thanks

Comment: what namespaces have you opened?

Comment: Uh, [what Pixels property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx)..?

Comment: @ildjarn - I think he is looking for this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixels(v=vs.95).aspx - why I asked about the namespaces.

Comment: @John : And also why I upvoted your comment. :-]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pixels` is a property of the [`System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347331%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class for Silverlight, that is different than the [`System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) class of the standard framework.

You should reference the Silverlight version of the framework to use the first class - and have the `Pixels` property - but then you will be writing a Silverlight application, not a standard Windows one.

To access the pixel values using the standard framework you can use the [`CopyPixels`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.copypixels.aspx) methods

Comment: Thanks. Playing with circa 2009-ish fsharp Silverlight raytracer samples. Not sure what current fsharp SL status/situation is.